# what is the best way to share session and cookie in sub domain?

Tags: php, session, cookies

how can i get the right cookie value at once ?
I set a cookie value in "fr.persun.com" ,
then I go to "de.persun.com" , 
but the cookie will not be de but fr, when I refresh the page ,the cookie will be de.
the two domain are using the same site files
what is the best way to share session and cookie in sub domain?

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    setcookie('country',substr(,$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,2),time()+3600*24*30,'/','.persun.com');    // saved country cookie in
    echo $_COOKIE['country'];
 ?>
```

Comment: manual knows all: Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling `print_r($_COOKIE);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: then how to refresh the self page at once in php